# Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn't there

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, new-users

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206494/shell-programming-with-html) was downvoted, and the downvote removed, and the user now has 3 rep, even though there are no reputation generating events on the user's page.

Comment: Sweeeeet. 30 free rep for new users.

Comment: @Ian: Only 2. -----------------

Comment: ...unless you could find fifteen people to downvote, and then restore...

Comment: At first I thought it was the users own votes that were removed until I realized he *can't* down vote. So technically you may be able to get 200 rep if people cast 100 down votes against you (lol) and then remove them.

Comment: They would have to remove them all at the same time though.

Comment: So 'status-bydesign' in this case is equivalent to 'status-toolazytofix', right?

Comment: @Brad, I don't think so... They just have to place the original down vote while the user has 1 rep. You're always given 2 rep when vote against you is removed, but down votes don't remove rep if you only have 1.

Comment: @Brad, as proof, I just gave the user 7 rep.

Comment: So if you really want to welcome a 1-rep user, downvote his question, then remove the downvote (rep 3), then upvote (13). Your "power" to increase his rep has increased from 10 points to 12.

Comment: Apparently, "toolazytofix" and "by design" was not true: it was fixed, and the reverse is now true, your reps are not restored: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29088/downvote-removed-score-of-downvoted-user-unchanged

Comment: Just tested, and it is still the case that rep can be granted by downvoting and removing the downvote

Comment: @Abel, the question referenced in your comment above is probably based on community wiki behaviour. It does not seem to refer to any fix.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is no longer the case.  Casting a downvote now records the *actual* value (0 change in this case) and reverses that 0 value upon removing it...the user will correctly stay at 1 reputation.

Answer (score 13):

It's "as designed" because the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/) says:

1. "A **down vote** on your Question or Answer **is removed: +2**".
2. "A user's reputation may not **drop below 1**".

I'm guessing a **[reputation recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rep-recalc)** will fix this "by design" anomaly.

Comment: a reputation recalc processes all things in order, so a user can receive 10 downvotes and a single upvote and still have a score of 6 - if the upvote was the last thing to happen.