# There is a bug where you can get free reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

This really is minor, and inconsequential, but it's a bug nonetheless.

Anyway, here it is.

Find a new user with 1 rep that has asked a question.  Downvote question. Remove downvote.  Voilà, 3 rep.

See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/59644/domain-default-changed) example, [daniel](https://serverfault.com/users/18609/daniel) [sic]

Or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/60027/no-history-for-sql-backup) example, [Jim](https://serverfault.com/users/18719/jim)

Comment: Just upvoting them isn't a bug, is it.

Comment: The same bug occurs to answers, see [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/11488/6969#29216). I came across this bug when adding and revoking a downvote on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5211225/427545).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn't there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, this has been [known for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2288#2288)... I don't think anyone is too concerned, given that it only works for users without any reputation, and it doesn't really give them much.

Comment: Fair enough - just thought I'd drop it in mixer :)

Comment: No worries - good that it's documented somewhere.

Comment: Now I'm wondering what would happen if several people downvoted, and they all cancelled...

Comment: @Izzy: (For the record.) It works, the rep stacks.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you do this to a user who is suspended? (Suspension sets your rep to 1, so you cannot perform basic tasks).

Comment: Can I use your account to test with?  The only downside is the reputation recalc that's required when you exit the box. (No one else is in timed suspension right now.)

Comment: How long will I be suspended?

Comment: A couple of minutes maximum. (It will say 1 day, but I'll lift the ban manually once I test voting.)

Comment: Suspended users can't ask questions here...are you talking about doing this on SO instead?

Comment: I was going to do it here and test with this answer and one of your other questions.  I can do it on SO, but the rep recalc might hurt a lot more on there.

Comment: I tested it against an answer earlier with a 1 rep suspended user. Nothing happened. This bug is against questions, so I had no case to test it against since I couldn't find a question that qualified. I'm not sure I want to undergo a rep-recalc on SO :)

Comment: No, I didn't think so. :)  That's alright, I'm sure someone will give me the opportunity to try it out sooner or later.

Comment: Sorry, man. If it had been here, I would be more than happy. But with the rep-recalc and the fact that suspended users already can't ask new questions, the scenario doesn't seem to be a great case to test against.

Comment: @Bill, you can test w/ my account.  Got nothing to lose...

Answer (score 0):

These inconsistencies will no longer happen.  As part of some large reputation changes, downvote reversals [will restore the correct amount of reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) (including adjusting for the reputation cap).