# How did I earn 13 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

How did I get to 13 rep?  I had a rep of 1, answered a question that got one upvote, and now I have 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One downvote, followed immediately by one up-vote from the same user. In your case, it was me - welcome to MetaSO! Only works when the user has a rep of 1.

Comment: I'll trust you and you 8K+ rep!!

Comment: If this is what happened, it is a bug. It created two points out of thin air...

Comment: It is - this was asked here in the past too.

Comment: It's been mentioned in the past. It may be a bug, but there's no easy way (short of a rep recalc) to fix it. If we get a rep recalc here on MSO and you don't have any rep associated with deleted answers your rep will fall by two points.

Comment: It's a bug that is "status-bydesign", because, you know, returning rep that a user never had is *clearly* intentional.

Comment: It's a bug that is "status-bydesign" because the impact is so negligible (a possible 1-time grant of 2 points) that it's probably not worth the effort to fix. :) (There should be a "status-not-freakin-worth-it" for these things.) :)

Comment: Well it can technically be gamed to an infinite amount of rep if the offenders are willing. Not a serious issue, but since the SO source is now a SAAS even the small bugs should be patched.

Comment: @Ian: The rep increase can only be 2 per user, surely you see that?

Comment: @Adam, no, it depends on the order that votes are cast, it's 2 per vote, per user. If done in the right order 30 users could add 60 rep per post to a new user, before adding another 300.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to get 13 is to start at 1, ask a question, get one upvote (+10), then accept an answer (+2).

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [There is a bug where you can get free reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/there-is-a-bug-where-you-can-get-free-reputation)

To summarize, through [unicorn power and waffle dust](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson) you magically went from 1 to 3 reputation.  The rest is history.

Comment: I was wondering where all these crumbs came from.  ;-)