# Possible Bug in Points System

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, voting, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There is a bug where you can get free reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/there-is-a-bug-where-you-can-get-free-reputation)

So here' what happens...

- New User A with 1 Rep asks a question that is not a real question
- User B Downvotes
- User C Upvotes (probably because he thinks the downvote was unnecessary)
- User A now displays 11 Rep
- User B removes his downvote
- User A shows 13 rep
- User B puts back his downvote
- User A shows 11 Rep

I would think that when user C upvotes, user A should have only 9 rep (10 - the 2 from the original downvote)

and certainly when User B removes his downvote, User A should not gain 2 rep.

Answer (score 2):

This magical rep gain of 2 points would be taken care of with a reputation recalc.

It is also less likely to happen now that the ability to undo your votes has been curtailed significantly and you would only be able to cause this within a very small window now.

Comment: yes, i noticed this.  but it would only take someone, that really wanted to change his/her vote, a quick retag to do this.

Comment: @Russ: It's also only 2 points. Ever. One time. Not gonna matter in the grand scheme of things.