# Quick downvote and undo of a new account causes +2 rep. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, voting, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn’t there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

I know a downvote causes the target to lose 2 rep points. Undoing the downvote naturally restores those 2 rep. However....

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850964/time-convert-in-javascript) from a new account (i.e. 1 rep) that I just downvoted. I then *un*-downvoted (and voted to close instead). I noticed (at least I *think* I noticed) the OPs rep went up by +2!

Is this a bug?

**Edit**

I just confirmed it again: someone just downvoted the OPs other duplicate question (now deleted), dropping the account to the minimum 1 rep. I downvoted and quickly un-did my vote, and sure enough, the OPs rep jumped back up to 3.

Comment: It's not worth making a special check for.  The change is minimal, only occurs on new users, and doesn't give any significant benefits from exploiting.  Rep recalcs (which happen about once a year or so) will 'fix' it.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/there-is-a-bug-where-you-can-get-free-reputation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21441/possible-bug-in-points-system http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there

Comment: we at Stack Overflow would like to wish you a free bonus of 2 rep! Enjoy!! :)