# Why does this new user have a reputation of 3?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There is a bug where you can get free reputation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/there-is-a-bug-where-you-can-get-free-reputation)

I'm just curious, does anyone know why [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244641) have a rep of 3 ? He only has 1 question that has been downvoted once and never upvoted. He never accepted an answer.

Could it be that someone answered his question, he accepted it and then the answerer deleted it ?

Comment: Yes, I know. Oh, Jeff was faster... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there