# Flagging a post before submitting the 5th close vote always results in flag being marked helpful

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, helpful-flags

Okay, there's nice workaround to get some free flag weight!

**What you need**

- 3k minimal,
- 10k for the easiest way

**Way to reproduce it**

- Find question with 4 close votes (10k [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/))
- Flag that question
- Vote to close that question

**Result:**
http://phpcode.eu/images/1315861512.php

All flags on closed questions are automatically marked as helpful!

Happy flagging! (This is a bug report, not a tutorial on how to work around the system)

Comment: That seems like the same situation as here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18507/155556 I don't think it matters that much and the affect is minimal at best

Comment: This *very specific* scenario will be tweaked next build.

Comment: @MarcGravell: can I know, how? How can this be prevented witout adding more work to mods ?

Comment: It sounds like [Jeff is saying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106353) that the flag is automatically dismissed as "None" in this situation.

Comment: @genesis [as per here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106353/flag-response-none) - in that scenario, the flag of the final voter is dismissed *without prejudice* (no plus, no minus).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and something that the moderators are aware of. I'd even argue that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), as long as you don't abuse it.

Every flag on a user's post is displayed in the profile page for that particular user (can be seen only by mods). This is helpful when action needs to be taken against them. It also shows who raised that flag. So if a post truly fits this description:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed

then flag it and close and get your free point! In other words, if you would've flagged it even without 4 close votes, then there is nothing wrong in flagging before closing. I do this sometimes if a post is so horribly bad, so that the mods will be aware of the issue if it comes to taking an action.

However, other flags are not dismissed. Flags to the moderator (you type something in) are not dismissed and if you flag "does not belong here", it automatically converts it to a close vote if you have 3k. Needless to say, spam/offensive flags should not be misused because of the repercussions it has for the flagged user.

Note that mods can also see your entire flagging history. So if you have a string of "very low quality" flags just before your close vote and the post is not worthy of it, then you better watch out.

Comment: Per the comment & link from Marc on the OP, this loophole has been closed.