# What happens if I flag a question that gets closed?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions, flag-history

I flagged a question with 4 close-votes.  It looks like a fifth person came and closed the question.  Under flag weight, there seemed to be no effect but the response was `none`.  What exactly does that mean, and under what circumstances will that show up?

Comment: To clarify, Jeff is correct, but ***you*** must have been the final closer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you flagged the question and then cast the last close vote on it.

[This is a loophole we recently "closed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106002/flagging-a-post-before-submitting-the-5th-close-vote-always-results-in-flag-being), so you don't get flag weight changes from that specifically.