# quirk with down-vote user with 1 rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn’t there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

If you down-vote an answer to a user with only `1` rep, then remove the down-vote their new rep is `3`.

Comment: Why do you people never bother to check if an issue has been reported before? Stop assuming you're a master bug hunter. We've had a zillion people find these issues before, and we're tired of it.

Comment: Apologies, I tried searching for it.  I could not find it.

Comment: "Welcome back to Old News Daily.  We have just been informed that the Japanese have bombed Pearl Harbor."

Comment: However, the massive popularity of this issue being reported should serve as an indication that Atwood's Angels are missing the point of the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Jeff Atwood's Modified Principle of Least Surprise: You will have the least surprise if you limit yourself to doing only those twelve things that we bothered testing.

Comment: He found a bug, and tried to search for it before reporting it. *Now he has two problems*. For heaven's sake, **fix the search functionality**.