# What happens when a new user asks 1st question and it's voted down several times?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Does s/he get a negative reputation?

Comment: Some people will wait for them to be upvoted at least once so that when they then apply their downvote of justice/cowardice/civic duty, it will look better than seeing their downvotes not count the rep down.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reputation is always at least 1. If a user has 1 reputation and is downvoted, he still has 1 reputation.

In fact, this leads to [a non-intuitive bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27058/quirk-with-down-vote-user-with-1-rep) which causes new users to gain 2 reputation if they are downvoted, and then the downvote is removed.

Comment: I was about to edit my post to add the +2 bug. You suck.

Comment: @Jon B: Stop being such a slowpoke, you Pokemon.

Comment: What did you say I did to your mom?

Comment: No, I'm talking about pocket monsters.

Comment: I've lost count, how many entendres are we up to now?

Comment: I'd like to show you my Pikachu, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

While rep can never go negative and a down-vote followed by a removal will "gain" the poster 2 points, this rep will disappear when a rep recalc is performed as the vote won't exist any more.

Answer (score 2):

There is no negative reputation. The minimum is 1.

Answer (score -1):

Reputation is an unsigned integer >= 1

Comment: You forgot to link to Welbog.