# Downvote removed, score of downvoted user unchanged

Tags: support, voting, specific-question, down-votes

In one of [my questions](https://serverfault.com/users/24901/abel) at ServerFault, I got downvoted and later, after I edited the question, the downvote was removed. On none of my questions I have received other votes, and the result went from `101` to `99` when downvoted, and remained after the downvote was removed.

From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there), it seems "by design" that the reverse should happen: reps go up, not down, when a downvote is removed.

Is that behavior fixed and reverse is now "by design"? After reps are removed as result of downvote on your questions, the reps will not be recovered? (in other words: updating your question to make it better is discouraged?).

Comment: You should have gotten those 2 points back according to how the system reverses unvotes.

Comment: Ask for a moderator to recalculate your rep.

Comment: It's not that much of a rep, I'm more active on SO, and wouldn't dare to ask the mods' precious time for just 2 points ;-) My main goal was to have it submitted as a bug (if it is one, but so it appears).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I have seen similar behavior.  It appeared to be part of switching to a community wiki.

The down vote was cast before it was a wiki and need a fair amount of rewording.  The question was updated and switched to a wiki and the down vote was changed to an up vote the lost rep was not returned.

Comment: this is definitely plausible

Comment: Looking through my questions' history, this seems to have happened indeed. It doesn't just make it plausible, it turns this from bug into feature (wiki's score up nor down).