# How does this user have some reputation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes

> EDIT: a fast acting moderator deleted the user's post (and his rep is at 1 again) but, for reference, the user's profile is at https://stackoverflow.com/users/442340.

This user asked the following blatantly off-topic question:

[image]

This is his only question and he has 6 down votes (including mine) and no up votes.  Checking his [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442340?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) shows only the -12 from those 6 down votes.  His reputation was actually higher than this before he got a few more down votes.

I do have a theory, that he was down voted when he posted the question and then several votes were removed by users within the 5 minute limit.  Would this cause a rep refund of 2 points, even though the user lost no rep?  Is it a potential exploit for gaining rep (if enough sock puppets were used)?

Comment: Though, as it seems, it's a spammer. The User 'Mubi' is answering the question in a very interesting way, and with a link which fits astonishing good to the question. I'll flag it.

Comment: A moot point now that I've destroyed both ;p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a down-vote is removed 2 points are added to the rep total *even if the rep was at 1*.

So in this case 7 people down-vote and the rep remains at 1.

One person removes their down-vote and 2 is added giving a rep of 3 and leaving 6 down-votes.

If you remove your down-vote the rep will increase to 5 (I think).

**Update:** this is no longer the case, [downvote reversals will restore the correct (if any) reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).

Comment: Tested and confirmed. That is weird... Aha, it's of course [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there).

Comment: @Georg - thanks for finding the link!

Comment: @Georg, @ChrisF: Then my theory was correct, although as I said in the question, he had more rep than that before I down voted and noticed, which makes me wonder if this was some kind of crazy experiment involving sock puppets.

Comment: @Andy Well, it's practicaly impossible to abuse that to gain any kind of reputation. The difference between 1 & 3 reputation is trivial.

Comment: @HoLy: I realize that, of course.  It would take an astounding amount of effort to pull something big like instantly gaining 100 reputation, I was just thinking that this particular incident seemed like a bit of an experiment.

Comment: @Georg - Does that [still apply?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29088/148317)

Comment: @Peter: That is a different corner-case which didn't apply here - my removed down-vote gave the user the 2 additional rep, ergo 1 → 1 → 3.

Answer (score 0):

May be he accepted an answer on another question that got subsequently deleted.

Comment: If that question got deleted, he would lose his reputation for accepting it.