# Who is the downvoter come in front of me

Tags: support, reputation, voting, discussion

Actually I want to see that what will be the effect on my "1" reputation when someone down vote me :)

Comment: I said downvote :(

Comment: [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: AWAN, you can't have negative reputation, unless you piss off user 1 :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1

Comment: All your votes are belong to us. +1. DON'T MAKE ME FAVORITE IT TOO ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never go below one. But predicting your next question: [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn’t there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there).

Comment: Then why it shows minus votes on my questions/answers. It should also not go to minus. If i am downvoted 200 times without 1 upvote then how can I know that how many up-votes are required to get my 1+ reputation.

Comment: @AWAN, why not? People's reputation can't go below 1. The plus/minus vote count for posts can. After getting 200 downvotes your reputation will still be 1, and you need just a single upvote for a question to gain 5 points and go to 6 (or to gain 10 on Meta, to get to 11), or a single upvote for an answer to gain 10 and go to 11 -- see the link I predicted you needed...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, you stay at 1. If you get an Upvote, I think the downvote then applies to only give you +8/+3

Comment: it should show reputation in minus :(

Comment: then why it shows minus votes on my questions/answers ?