# Reversing a downvote on a one rep user results in a gain of 2 rep

Tags: bug, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn’t there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

Consider this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668051/whitespace-ingoring-languages-closed

Note how (at the time of this writing) the user has 3 rep and no up or down votes.

I accidentally clicked the down arrow on the question, and removed my downvote. When the downvote was processed, the system tried to take away 2 rep from the user, but it could not, as the user only had 1 rep to begin with. When the downvote was removed, the system tried to give the user 2 rep back, which worked just fine. Thus, the user has 3 rep.

I understand this isn't the average case but it's a significant enough anomaly that I figured I'd report it.