# A toggling of down vote on a user with reputation 1 makes his reputation 3

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn’t there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

Reproduction steps
1. Down vote on answer of a user with reputation 1.
2. Take back your down vote by clicking the same button again.

Just see that I did it for [Max Bolingbroke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419369/max-bolingbroke) and [KThinks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/3906/kthinks) users.