# How come this new user start with 3 rep?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn't there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/601496/user601496

Is this a bug or a new feature I don't know of?

Comment: @ChrisF: an exact duplication. How come I failed to find that.

Comment: Search isn't exact. It's better than it was, but it's not perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somebody had downvoted his question or answer and then reverted their downvote. In that case the reputation increases by two for a new user who has rep 1. This is a bug which is already mentioned in meta before.

[Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn't there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

Comment: Oh, I get it. Some might say it's "as designed". Like the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/ "How does “Reputation” work?") says: **"A down vote on your Question or Answer is removed: +2"** and **"A user's reputation may not drop below 1"**.