# Reputation of new users with downvoted question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, down-votes, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn't there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there)

I've spotted a problem [question on travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1054/19). At that moment it had `-1` score.
I've added another one `-1` vote, but got an error alert. After refreshing I've seen that question has the `-2` votes, and I've decided to view the author profile.

At that page his question had only one `-1` vote, so I decided to readd my down vote.

So I removed my `-1` and refreshed the page. And at that moment of time user had reputation score equal to `3`. No upvotes, no suggested edits, nothing at all.

After that I've add the `-1` to question, and user got his `1` in the reputation. But if I remove my vote, user get his `2` to the reputation score.

Is it normal?