# Are the -2's for downvotes on 1-rep users permanently written off?

Tags: discussion, reputation

When we downvote a 1-rep user, his/her rep doesn't change since [we don't do negative reps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/134327).

**Question:** Is the `-2` completely written off, or would it be taken into account **during recalc** if the user has gained some reps since the downvote?

I'd suspect the answer would be former but I'm curious to know for sure.

---

Looking at the rep for [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172930/denys-wessels?tab=reputation) who had his first question downvoted and then upvoted, we see the expected result where the `-2` is written off and his rep goes up to 6.

[image: 6 != 3]

This is sensible since reps are accumulated on a vote-by-vote basis and it doesn't make sense to have to dig into the rep history to handle each vote.

Even in the screenshot we see a discrepancy between the total rep and the daily rep shown. Will this remain after a recalc?

Comment: Even more: if I downvote, and remove that downvote, the users ends up with +3: [Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn't there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there). However, I indeed wonder what a recalc would do.

Comment: Nice thought in a comment by [Rowland](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there/77711#77711): *a reputation recalc processes all things in order*.

Comment: @Arjan if the rep recalc does indeed process all thins in order, then that answers my question and the relevant -2's will indeed be written off.

Comment: I'm considering making a sock and asking a test question...

Comment: ...but not if the vote is not somehow marked as such. Like: 1) Answer A upvoted, score 11. 2) Answer B downvoted 7 times, score 1 (not -3). 3) Answer C downvoted, score still 1. 4) Answer B deleted. 5) Recalc: 1 + 10 - 2 = 9?

Comment: @John it did cross my mind to troll on one of the SE sites just to test it out, but decided it would be faster and more `*cough*` responsible to simply ask on meta.

Comment: I just noticed a difference between an account [with downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113588/nutch1-3-cannot-run-program-chmod-cannot-allocate-memory) that shows 1 rep as [This user has no recent **positive** reputation changes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mVQ4A.png), where another account without such downvotes shows 1 rep as [This user has no reputation changes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UrbWT.png). Of course we already knew that the system knows about all downvotes. Still interesting.

Comment: As an aside, slightly related: up till February 2012, voting down a 1 rep user and then removing that downvote, might yield a reputation of 3. That [is no longer the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there/123859#123859).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The down-votes on users with a reputation equal to 1 doesn't have effect when the user gain reputation. If a user with reputation equal to 1 writes a question that is down-voted twice, and then writes an answer that is up-voted once, his reputation will become 11, not 7. Not even a reputation recalc would change the reputation from 11 to 7, whenever the recalc is automatically triggered by the system, or manually triggered by the user.

Comment: ...but what if a recalc is done?

Comment: A recalc would not change the reputation from 11 to 9, in my example.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "manually *trigger by* the user"? I noticed you're avid  "English Language and Usage" user so I'm not really sure.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd My reputation on EL&U doesn't make me a native speaker: I can choose the wrong word too. `;)`

Comment: Cheers, I feel much better now. :D

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Me too! `;)`

Answer (score 6):

They are not taken into account.  If they were, then the person effectively "had" negative points, but it wasn't shown.

A person with 1 rep can have a question with -10 votes on it.  As soon as I upvote the question to -9, that person's rep becomes 6.  If someone else comes along and downvotes it back to -10, then their rep becomes 4, because they just lost 2 points from that *last* down vote.

A manual or system-wide recalc should not change that equation.

Comment: That much I'm aware of. From an implementation point of view, it's more efficient to update the reps on a vote-by-vote basis and not have to dig into the rep history. I'm wondering what happens on recalc.

Comment: @ShawnChin Nothing should change on a recalc.  If the recalc did it differently, then that would effectively put the person into negative rep territory.

Comment: How do you know a recalc doesn't affect this?

Comment: @LarsTech a recalc could potentially sum up all votes and set to 1 if it is negative. This will give a different value compared to the run-time resetting on negative values.

Comment: @Arjan I changed my answer to "should not" vs "does not" since I don't have access to the source code.  But I've watched my own recalc results and you can see how it computes the rep number.  If a recalc didn't do the calculations based on "when" the points were upvoted or downvoted, it would be a serious flaw in the recalc method.