# Regression of behavior on removal of downvote to 1-rep user's question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, voting, down-votes

Removing a downvote on a post by a user with one rep point [is not supposed to increase that user's reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there/123859).

This occurred the other day, however:
[image]

[image]

Uh-oh!

(Devs/mods: there's [a deleted comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there/123859#comment564660_123859) under [Nick Craver's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123859/159251) to the original report of this which contains the question ID and non-anonymized screenshots, if you need 'em.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a regression.

The question was also upvoted, before it was downvoted again to the point where the asker got back to 1 reputation. That upvote was withdrawn as well, but while you were casting and retracting your downvotes, it was in effect. Yours actually cost the OP 2 rep. So when that downvote was reversed, he got back some of the rep he'd lost.

Comment: According to the user's reputation timeline, the question wasn't upvoted until 15 minutes after these screenshots.

Comment: @JoshCaswell There was one more upvote before that. It was withdrawn as well, but while you were casting and retracting your downvotes, it was in effect. Other downvotes on the question behave exactly as Nick described in his answer and results in 0 rep changes. Yours actually cost the OP 2 rep. Your final downvote that you didn't retract had a 0 rep effect on the poster, so if you were to retract it now, I bet it would not result in a rep increase.

Comment: Confirmed. My bug report is erroneous, but the key was the withdrawn upvote that I have no way to see. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Any time. :) I should've been more clear in my original answer, sorry.