# Upvoting a 1 reputation bug

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I'll give an example of what I think to be a bug.

Say someone has 1 reputation. I vote up, he now has 6. Someone vote him down, he now has 4. I cancel my upvote, he now has 1. I upvote him again, he now has 6, and not 4. Please confirm if this is indeed a bug.

[This is the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255409/select-a-not-sequential-record-in-sql), he has 6 reputation even tho he's downvoted once and upvoted once. (and down voted once on another question even! So he should have technically 2 reputation.)

Comment: Long story short: it's a duplicate. I just can't find the original question. But this has been asked times before and answered at least once.

Comment: @mast I'm sorry if it did get asked before, I didn't find an answer anywhere that's why I asked :)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, but by design.

Reputation can't go below one, thus downvotes that bring your reputation below one have no influence on your reputation beyond that. That means the order of votes is important: a 1-rep user that receives a downvote, and then an upvote, has more reputation than a 1-rep user receiving an upvote, then a downvote.

This means that on rare occasions, retracting and re-casting an upvote can indeed increase reputation. And retracting and re-casting a downvote can decrease reputation in a similar way.

Read more: [Why does reputation start at 1, and have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/369403) and [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/369403)